# Skip first N elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know, how can I skip first N elements in JQuery. Something like this:

```
<div id="test">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    ...
</div>

$('#test > div').skip(2)
```

Should return

```
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
...
```

I know I can just use `:not(:first-child):not(:first-child + div)...` selector N times, but is there a better way?

Comment: [jQuery Selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [jQuery Traversing/Filtering API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/) Docs are the first place you should look.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

jQuery has a [gt selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/). (Greater than).

```
$('#test > div:gt(1)')
```

Or you can use the [slice function](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$('#test > div').slice(2)
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function, it gives you the subset of elements based on its index.

```
$('#test > div').slice( 2 )
```

*Reference:* http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `:gt` selector: http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/
Note that you start counting from 0 here.

Try:

```
$('#test > div:gt(1)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip just the first one - example:

```
$("#spaccordion li:gt(0)").addClass("collapsed");
```

All `<li>` items will have class "collapsed" except the first one