# selecting element number 6 and onwards with jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

OK, so I have a container with a bunch of children in it, but I want to only show the 1st 5 elements and hide() the rest.

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>seven</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>eight</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>nine</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>ten</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>eleven</li> <!-- hide me -->
</ul>
```

I found another example, but it only hides the 3rd one from last.

```
$('li').eq(-3).hide();​
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15213968/559079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the selector [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

   > Description: Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.

```js
$('li:gt(4)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>seven</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>eight</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>nine</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>ten</li> <!-- hide me -->
    <li>eleven</li> <!-- hide me -->
</ul>
```