# How to hide all the divs of each class except first class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some divs of same class,I need to hide all the div of each class except first one,but here class like critical or major can be change based on condition.it wont be always same.Here is the html and script below.

### HTML

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div id="critical">
<h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
</div>
<div id="critical">
<h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
</div>
<div id="critical">
<h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
</div>
<div id="major">
<h4 id="test" class="major">major</h4>
</div>
<div id="major">
<h4 id="test" class="major">major</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

### SCRIPT

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('critical').forEach(function(el,i){ i !== 0 && el.setAttribute('hidden','')});`

Comment: You really should not be setting multiple instances of the same ID in your HTML.  You're asking for hard-to-debug problems that way.  Also, your question has been asked and answered previously right here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213961/skip-first-n-elements-in-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip first N elements in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213961/skip-first-n-elements-in-jquery)

Comment: I need to hide all div of each class except first one and here class are coming dynamically it may change also so I cannot use critical always..Duplicate question is different than this

Comment: Is there only ever going to be a single class?

Comment: The parent div with id `critical'  will not change  too though right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small, reusable, easy-to-understand function.

```js
$(function() {
  function hideExceptFirst(selector) {
    var i = 0;
    $(selector).each(function() {
      if (i > 0) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
      i++;
    });
  }
  hideExceptFirst('.critical');
  hideExceptFirst('.major');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div id="critical">
    <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="critical">
    <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="critical">
    <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical 3</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="major">
    <h4 id="test" class="major">major 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="major">
    <h4 id="test" class="major">major 2</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: critical and major are dynamic class in my project it will change as per condition which is coming from json,so directly I cannot use those class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :not and :first selector

```
$('.critical:not(:first)').hide();
```

Comment: I need to hide all div of each class except first one and here class are coming dynamically it may change also so I cannot use critical always

Answer (score 0):

With the example you have the only items with classes are the H4 elements.  Using your example if the names will change dynamically you could do it this way:

Keeping an array of which classes that have already been filtered.  You could go through each DIV and treat IDs like classes but that doesn't conform with HTML standards.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var groups = [];

  $("h4").each(function(){
    var thisGroup = $(this).attr("class");
    if(groups.indexOf(thisGroup) > -1){
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
    else{
      groups.push(thisGroup);
    }   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
<div id="critical">
<h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
</div>
<div id="critical">
<h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
</div>
<div id="critical">
<h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
</div>
<div id="major">
<h4 id="test" class="major">major</h4>
</div>
<div id="major">
<h4 id="test" class="major">major</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one attempt that uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to easily get everything but the first element for a class name.

For the sample HTML this will work when the input is "critical" or "major" (without quotes).

```js
function hideAllButOneClass() {
  const classInput = document.getElementById('classInput').value;
  const queryClass = '.' + classInput;
  const instancesOfClassName = $(queryClass);
  // destructuring here
  const [first, ...rest] = instancesOfClassName;
  rest.forEach(entry => {
    const entryParent = $(entry).parent()[0];
    $(entryParent).hide();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="classInput">Class to hide<input ref="classInput" id="classInput" type="text"/>
<button onclick="hideAllButOneClass()">Hide class (except first)</button>
  
<div class="main">
 <div id="critical">
 <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
 </div>
 <div id="critical">
 <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
 </div>
 <div id="critical">
 <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical</h4>
 </div>
 <div id="major">
 <h4 id="test" class="major">major</h4>
 </div>
 <div id="major">
 <h4 id="test" class="major">major</h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you at least know they are wrapped by the `.main` element, you can try traversing elements one by one, and then hide an element if it have an already visited class. Check next example.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    let targets = $(".main > div");
    let visitedClasses = [];

    targets.each(function()
    {
        let innerH4 = $(this).find("h4");

        if (visitedClasses.includes(innerH4.attr("class")))
           $(this).hide();
        else
           visitedClasses.push(innerH4.attr("class"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div id="critical">
    <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="critical">
    <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="critical">
    <h4 id="test" class="critical">critical 3</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="major">
    <h4 id="test" class="major">major 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div id="major">
    <h4 id="test" class="major">major 2</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a side note, you should **really skip** the duplication of `id` attributes for multiple elements.